# Segfault for C++ Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

Designed my first BST but for some reason it segfaults when I add more than 2 items. Cant seem to figure out why. I think int has to do with my insert function within Node. The main stops working after  t.insert(5) and t.insert(10);

**Tree.CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tree.h"
 

using namespace std;

Node::Node(int obj)
{
    value = obj;
}
void Node::set(int obj){
    int value = obj;
}

bool Node::member(int obj) const{
    if(obj<value){
        if(left == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            return left -> member(obj);
    }
    if(obj>value){
        if(right == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            return right -> member(obj);
    }
return true;
}

void Node::insert(int obj){
    if(obj < value){
        if(left == NULL)
            left = new Node(obj);
        else
            left -> insert(obj);
    }
    if(obj > value){
        if(right == NULL)
            right = new Node(obj);
        else
            left -> insert(obj);
    }
}

Tree::Tree()
{
    root = NULL;
}

bool Tree::member(int obj) const{
    if(root == NULL)
        return false;
    else
        return root -> member(obj);

}

void Tree::insert(int obj){
    if(root == NULL)
        root = new Node(obj);
    else
        root -> insert(obj);
}
```

I had to convert this code from SmallTalk. I don't know if the code was 100% translatable. That could be the issue as well.

Comment: `# ifndef TREE_H
# define TREE_H

class Node {
    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;

public:
    Node(int);
    void insert(int);
    bool member(int) const;
    void set(int);
};

class Tree {
    Node *root;

public:
    Tree();
    void insert(int);
    bool member(int) const;
};

# endif  `

Comment: Looks like the last line of Node::insert(int should be right -> insert(obj);